# Is it possible to do recording on blaze meter while running protractor automation test?

Tags: jmeter, protractor

We have a lot of UI automation scripts written in Typescript and we use Protractor with the Jasmine test framework to run them. They work great and now we want to do load testing with jMeter.

Is it possible to hook up these UI tests in jMeter instead of recording the same flows again separately?

I have read that Loadrunner allowed using winrunner scripts from the UI automation. I wanted to do something similar with my UI tests and jMeter. Is it feasible?

Answer (score 0):

You can record your Protractor tests using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder) as follows:

1. Start JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder. The easiest way of doing this is using [JMeter Templates](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#test_plan_building) feature - it will produce a good configuration for recording
2. Configure your Protractor tests to use [JMeter's HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder as the proxy](https://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#using-a-proxy)

   ```
   exports.config = {
       seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
       capabilities: {
           browserName: 'firefox',
           proxy: {
               proxyType: 'manual',
               httpProxy: 'localhost:8888',
               sslProxy: 'localhost:8888'
           }
       }
       framework: 'jasmine',
       //etc
   ```
3. Run your Protractor tests
4. JMeter will store the requests under the [Recording Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Recording_Controller)

---

If you want to record using BlazeMeter - omit step #1 and in step #2 use hostname and port of the [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder)

Comment: As i am new in this i don't understand how to do this "If you want to record using BlazeMeter - omit step #1 and in step #2 use hostname and port of the BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder" can you please elaborate? how blaze meter records while running protractor automation test?

Comment: If you configure your test to use [BlazeMeter Proxy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDKqn.png) the requests from the browser will go to the application under test **through this proxy** therefore it will be able to record the traffic and create the test plan. Moreover, the proxy will automatically detect and handle dynamic parameters, in other words will perform automated **correlation**, check out [How to Cut Your JMeter Scripting Time by 80%](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-cut-your-jmeter-scripting-time-80 to learn more.